# Why is my AdMob code leaking in my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, admob

I have included AdMob in my iphone app.  I have the following code in my viewDidLoad method:

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
               initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                        0.0,
                                        320,
                                        50)];



// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
bannerView_.adUnitID = ADMOB_BANNER_UNIT_ID;

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
r.testing = YES;
[bannerView_ loadRequest:r];
[r release];
```

This leaks.  When I comment out the second last line ( [bannerView_ loadRequest:r]; ), the leak disappears.  The only thing I changed in this code from the example provided by Google was to introduce the variable r so I could put AdMob in testing mode.  In the code supplied by Google, bannerView_ is released by viewDidUnload.  I looked for the loadRequest method but all I found was a definition in the GADBannerView.h file.  As far as I can tell, there is no GADBannerView.m file, which seems weird in itself.  Anyway, any tips would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this [AdMediator](https://github.com/rajdn/AdMediator) - it is very simple to configure and you don't have to worry about AdMob and iAds (if you want to use it) :

> will swap in AdMob ads if no iAds are
>   available.

Answer (score 0):

Are you releasing bannerView_ in your dealloc method or somewhere else appropriate ?

Instead of:

`GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];`

You could try:

`GADRequest *r = [GADRequest request];`